# tcpdump TCP Header offset 13

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I am trying to understand how `tcpdump` works and trying to read TCP header control flags SYN,ACK etc.

After researching online I came to know that the control flags are available at offset 13 and I need to use tcp[13] however I am not able to understand how this value 13 is been calculated.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Read RFC 793 section 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP[13] is an array of bits (flags). When they're set to a 1 they're enabled, when they're a 0 they're disabled.

These `tcpdump` commands show how you can take the collection of TCP[13] bits and do bit-wise ands to test if the bits are enabled:

```
Show all URG packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 32 != 0'

Show all ACK packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 16 != 0'

Show all PSH packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 8 != 0'

Show all RST packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 4 != 0'

Show all SYN packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 2 != 0'

Show all FIN packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 1 != 0'

Show all SYN-ACK packets:
# tcpdump 'tcp[13] = 18
```

The referenced URL (below) had this bullet which explains it as well:

> Keep in mind the reasons these filters work. The filters above find these various packets because tcp[13] looks at offset 13 in the TCP header, the number represents the location within the byte, and the !=0 means that the flag in question is set to 1, i.e. it’s on.

#### TCP Header

If you take a look at the [RFC 793 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1) as well as this article on [tcpdump advanced filters](https://www.wains.be/pub/networking/tcpdump_advanced_filters.txt) it becomes more obvious.

```
TCP header
----------

    0                   1                   2                   3   
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |                        Sequence Number                        |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |  Data |       |C|E|U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
    | Offset|  Res. |W|C|R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             | 
    |       |       |R|E|G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |                             data                              |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

- Matching any TCP traffic with a source port > 1024
# tcpdump -i eth1 'tcp[0:2] > 1024'

- Matching TCP traffic with particular flag combinations

The flags are defined in the 14th byte of the TCP header.

    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |C|E|U|A|P|R|S|F|
    |W|C|R|C|S|S|Y|I|
    |R|E|G|K|H|T|N|N|
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

**NOTE:** These are the flags we're interested.

#### Calculating flag's position

*You count the bytes (8 bits) from the top, numbering them at 0:*

- So *"Source Port"* & *"Destination Port"* would make up bytes 0, 1, 2, & 3.
- The next row, *"Sequence Number"*, would be 4-7.
- *"Acknowledge Number"* would be bytes 8-11.
- *"Data Offset" & "Res."* would be byte 12.
- That takes you to byte 13, the bits in this byte are the flags.

#### Bit order

I'll also mention that the number stored in byte 13 is ordered such that:

- bit 1 = *FIN*
- bit 2 = *SYN*
- bit 4 = *RST*
- bit 8 = *PSH*
- bit 16 = *ACK*
- bit 32 = *URG*

#### References

- [tcpdump - reading tcp flags](https://gist.github.com/slmingol/ceefd4f49840b3302e055886d679456d)